# Not hitting breakpoints attached to NUnit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, nunit-2.5

I'm using the latest NUnit, 2.5.9, on Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010 Premium, and the projects are .Net 3.5.

The problem is that I attach to NUnit (there is NOT an nunit-agent appearing), and symbols are loading, but my break points aren't being hit.  There is no error indicator next to the breakpoint indicating something is wrong.

The first run seems to take some time to start the test, but subsequent runs after that seem to complete almost instantly.  I assume because StructureMap (required for the objects i'm testing) has already done its thing and doesn't need to repeat that setup.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Need to see some code please, maybe screenshots of the test suite.  Need to see the results from nunit, need to see your test taht you are trying to debug, and any Setup functions

Comment: Thanks; it wasn't my code though, it was something in Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured out the answer.  I reset all of my settings to the standard `Visual C# Development Settings` and debugging suddenly works again.

I'm not sure which setting got everything back on the right track; I didn't see a "disable debugging while debugging setting."